# On Android, why the getRunningProcesses() returns much less than the TOP command?

Tags: android, process

When I used getRunningProcesses(), I got about 20~30 processes.

However, when I used the TOP command in an Android terminal, I saw more than 80 processes. I found some processes owned by "root" have zero memory consumption.

What cause the differences? Are some of the processes found by TOP not currently running?

Comment: are you talking about ActivityManager. getRunningAppProcesses ?

Comment: @nandeesh Yes, nandeesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top` shows all processes running on the operating system. Whereas  `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses` shows only processes started by Android.

Root owned processes are usually started by linux kernel for event handling , where as processes returned by `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses` are only those started by Android framework

Answer (score 0):

Android runs a lot of [services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Those services you do not want to close because Android needs them to run. Here is some more information about services:

- A Service is not a separate process. The Service object itself does not imply it is running in its own process; unless otherwise specified, it runs in the same process as the application it is part of.
- A Service is not a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors).

Also read [Android Developers -  Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

Comment: Do you mean the #ProcessesByTop = #getRunningProcesses() + #getRunningServices() ?